# PyAutoGUI screenshots my only background (Mac OS)

Tags: python, macos, screenshot, pyautogui

I'm using the pyautogui screenshot tool for a project and it's grabbing only my background and I haven't seen a solution to solve it yet. Does this always happen for Mac OS or is this just a me problem? I've also used the screenshot library but that returned a background only as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give access to your IDE for screen recording. There exist a solved issue on GitHub, you can check it from here: https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss/issues/134